# Has not unique limit points but still Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

We know Hausdroff space any sequence of points of X converges to at most one point of X.I thik that if the sequence has two limit points then X can not be Hausdroff space.If we take x,y as two distinct limit points and then by the definition of limit point,we assume that for any neighbourhood of x and y,say U and V respectively, U and V contains all the terms of the sequence except first finite number terms.So U and V which are arbitrary open sets containg x and y respectively,can not be disjoint.Hence X is not Hausdorff space.Am i correct?Any interesting result related on this topic is always welcome.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

A space is called UL if convergent sequences have unique limits. i.e. if $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \to y$ in $X$ then $x=y$.
It is well known that $X$ Hausdorff implies $X$ is UL: suppose $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \to y$ in $X$. Suppose that $x \neq y$. Then there are by Hausdorffness two open sets $U$ and $V$ of $X$ such that $x \in U, y \in V, U \cap V = \emptyset$.

Then as $x \in U$ and $x_n \to x$, there is some $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\forall n \ge N_1: x_n \in U$$

and similarly A $y \in V$ and $x_n \to y$ as well, there is some $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\forall n \ge N_2: x_n \in V$$

If now $M = \max(N_1, N_2)$, then $x_M \in U$ as $M \ge N_1$ and $x_M \in V$ as $m \ge N_2$, contradicting that $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

So if $X$ is not UL (there is a sequence with two limits) $X$ is not Hausdorff (as shown by this implication).

There exist spaces $X$ that are UL but not Hausdorff, the easiest of which (I think) is the co-countable topology on an uncountable set, whose only convergent sequences are the ones that are eventually constantly equal to their limit, but which is not Hausdorff in a strong way (all non-empty open sets intersect).

Note that UL implies that $X$ is $T_1$ because if $\{x\}$ wouldn't be closed, there would be a point $y \in \overline{\{x\}}, t \neq x$, and then the constant sequence $x,x,\ldots$ would converge to both $x$ and $y$.

There are other properties between $T_1$ and $T_2$, e.g. $X$ is called KC when all of its compact subsets are closed. It is well-known that $T_2$ implies KC, and KC trivially implies $T_1$ (as all finite sets are compact, thus closed).

It's also the case that KC spaces are UL: suppose $x_n \to x$, and $x_n \to y$ with $x \neq y$ in a KC space. Then $C  =\{x_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{x\}$ is compact (a convergent sequence with a limit is always compact) but $y \in \overline{C}\setminus C$ so $C$ is not closed, contradiction.